# Nginx Wildcard for try_files

Tags: nginx

So I'm trying to setup a default nginx config file that can be deployed across numerous docker image with different website configs in each container. It is currently set as below:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;

   root /var/www/;
   index index.php index.html;

   server_name localhost;
   include php5-fpm.conf;


   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
   }

   location /status {
           stub_status on;
           access_log   off;
           allow 127.0.0.1;
           deny all;
   }
```

}

The problem is that it doesn't work for static sites that use index.htm or index.html

I can edit the location section like below and then the site will work. Is there any way to get nginx to use a wildcard, so index.* and it will use whichever index file it finds? index.* by itself does not work so not sure what needs to be added/removed...

```
       location / {
           try_files $uri /index.htm?q=$request_uri;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fixated on the wrong part of `try_files`.

The part relevant to what you want is `$uri/`, with the trailing slash, which you seem to have removed. This bit causes nginx to try all of the files listed in the `index` directive.

You should put this part back in `try_files` and then edit the `index` directive to include the filenames you want.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I added index.htm to the index directive and it works 100%. I was fixated on the wrong part as you said.